# C++: C string to std:string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a C string to std::string using a function. The function works properly on a 64-bit `gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)`. But when I compile it with `-O2` or `-O3` optimization it segfaults. It works with `-O1` though. Can anyone suggest a fix or a work around on this please? The function is as below:

```
void make_name(unsigned const &i, string &h_file)
{
        char h_str[10];
        sprintf(h_str, "tmp/%09d.hb", i);
        h_file = string(h_str);
}
```

Comment: You're doing more than converting a c-string to an `std::string` here. That could be the problem. If you think you have a problem with X, write a test-case that does X and nothing else.

Comment: Goodness gracious - you've got a 10 character buffer and you're trying to print 16 characters plus the NUL into it... 'twas never going to end well.

Comment: Never use `sprintf`, always `snprintf(h_str, sizeof(h_str), "tmp/%09d.hb", i);`

Comment: The bigger question, why did it work for  -01.

Comment: Why is the `unsigned int` passed by const reference?

Comment: It worked for `-O1` for the same reason it may work on a blue moon. Undefined behaviour means anything can happen and this includes _correct_ behaviour. That is, in fact, one of the most insidious things about UB, I'd prefer it myself if it always failed by delivering a short sharp electrical shock to the developers reproductive organs :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `std::extent` has the advantage over `sizeof` that it blows up if you fail to pass an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple: provide a sufficient buffer. Or use `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 5):

```
char h_str[10];
sprintf(h_str, "tmp/%09d.hb", i);
```

This is undefined behaviour. You're trying to write some seventeen bytes of data into a ten-byte array:

- `tmp/` is four.
- `%09d` will expand to at least nine.
- `.hd` is three.
- string terminator `\0` is one.

Don't do that. Undefined behaviour means all guarantees of functionality are null and void.

---

In fact, if you want to be a truly decent C++ developer, you should probably avoid the legacy stuff as much as possible.

It's fine while learning and for library code that needs to run in both C and C++. But, for C++ code, using the non-legacy parts of the language is far more robust.

The following program shows how you could do this *without* having to revert to the legacy C stuff in `cstdio/stdio.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void make_name (unsigned int i, string &h_file) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "tmp/" << setw(9) << setfill('0') << i << ".hb";
    h_file = ss.str();
}


int main() {
    string s;
    make_name (42u, s);
    cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

> As an aside, you'll see I've changed your method signature to pass `i` by value. That's because I'm not sure there's any advantage to doing it as a `const` reference. Feel free to change it back if you *do* find an advantage.

Comment: The problem is that the C++ streams for many use cases suck badly, including this one... Are we seriously advocating that that mess of stream manipulators is any better than the equivalent `printf`? (bonus question: which of those manipulators is sticky, if any? Hell if I know.) Basic string formatting got an order of magnitude easier since I wrote an `sprintf`-like function which handles the reallocation (if needed), returns an `std::string` and is marked with the right gcc attribute so that it catches any type error - easy to use and type safe. End of manipulators idiocy.

Comment: @Matteo: I would say they _are_ better because they apparently prevent buffer overflow :-) And, if you stick to using `printf`, you'll never _learn_ which is sticky. Bonus answer, it doesn't matter here because the stickiness applies only to the single short-lived instance of `ss`.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to never use a C-string.

```
std::string make_name(unsigned i)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << "tmp/" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(9) << i << ".hb";
    return std::move(str.str());
}
```